# Have PyQt5 Labels dynamically update while sending http requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-asyncio

So I've been working on a async python **scraper** with http requests based on modules. So for that I've been using asks and importlib, and I'd like to make a simple little GUI that updates with the status codes of requests. And I did.

Everything is great, but I seem to have an issue as the requests are sent sucessfully, the GUI shows up, but it only shows up once all the requests are sent, and not dynamically while the requests are being sent

I've been playing around with tutorials and Qtimer, but in all the tutorials and help threads I've seen such as:

- https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2013-July/033053.html
- [PyQt5: Updating Label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43526507/pyqt5-updating-label)

I have tried to implement the code to my situation, but the only thing I've manage to do is for the GUI to show up at the same time the requests are sent, but it stays frozen (not responding) until all the requests are finished

```
import trio
from asks import Session
import importlib
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import qdarkstyle
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())


module = importlib.import_module("get_module")
good = 0
bad = 0
total = 0

class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        global good, bad, total
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Status Codes")

        self.central_widget = QWidget()               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)    
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        
        self.resize(500, 350)
        ok = QLabel("200: <font color='green'>0</font>")
        ok.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        bad = QLabel("400: <font color='yellow'>0</font>")
        bad.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        total = QLabel("Total: <font color='#00FF00'>0</font>")
        total.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        r_total, r_good, r_bad  = self.check()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: self.updateLabels(r_total, r_good, r_bad))
        lay.addWidget(ok)
        lay.addWidget(bad)
        lay.addWidget(total)
        self.show()
        

    def check(self):
        async def worker1(s):
            global ok
            global bad
            global total
            if module.method.lower() == "get":
                r = await s.get(module.request(), params=module.settings())
            elif module.method.lower() == "post":
                r = await s.post(module.request(), data=module.settings())
            if any(x in r.status_code for x in module.error):
                print("BAD -- " + module.request())
                r_total += 1
                r_invalid += 1
            else:
                print("GOOD -- " + module.request())
                r_total += 1
                r_valid += 1
                print(r.text)
        async def worker2(s):
            global ok
            global bad
            global total
            if module.method.lower() == "get":
                r = await s.get(module.request(), params=module.settings())
            elif module.method.lower() == "post":
                r = await s.post(module.request(), data=module.settings())
            if any(x in r.status_code for x in module.error):
                print("BAD -- " + module.request())
                r_total += 1
                r_invalid += 1
            else:
                print("GOOD -- " + module.request())
                r_total += 1
                r_valid += 1
                print(r.text)                    
            
    async def example():
            
        s = Session(connections=module.connections)
        for i in range(10):
            async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
                nursery.start_soon(worker1, s)
                nursery.start_soon(worker2, s)

        trio.run(example)
        print("Total:", r_total)
        print("Total good:", r_valid)
        print("Total bad:", r_invalid)
        return r_total, r_valid, r_invalid
    def updateLabels(self, r_total, r_card, r_invalid):
        good.setText("200: <font color='green'>%s</font>" % (r_valid))
        bad.setText("400: <font color='#00FF00'>%s</font>" % (r_invalid))
        total.setText("Total: <font color='#F40D30'>%s</font>" % (r.total))

        
    
             
if __name__ == '__main__':        
    ex = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now what I would like it to do is that the GUI shows up and that dynamically (or every 1 second) the 200, 400 and total labels show how many requests have been made, and how many returned 200 and 400.

However instead it'll show them (it does show the total, total 200 and total 400) but only once all the requests are finished and not dynamically on the side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous tasks block the thread of the GUI, so those tasks must be executed in another thread and send it through signals to the GUI, also that allows us to separate the business logic and the GUI having a cleaner code:

**get_module.py**

```py
# coding: utf8

#======================= IMPORT AREA =======================
#here's where you import any module needed for the website
from random import randint

#===========================================================

#====================== SETTINGS AREA ======================
#here's where you declare the settings of the website such
#as method, error key, success key, custom settings, etc...
name = "GET Test Config"
method = 'GET' #Method is either GET, POST or CUSTOM
error = ['400', '401', '402', '403', '404', '405', '406', '407', '408', '409', '410', '411', '412', '413', '414', '415', '416', '417', '418', '421', '422', '423', '424', '425', '426', '428', '429', '431', '451','500', '501', '502', '503', '504', '505', '506', '507', '508', '510', '511']
connections = 5
#===========================================================

#====================== DEFINITON AREA =====================
#here's where the definitions are made.
#There's 2 defs:
#def request(): Which returns the url (with or without modifications)
#def settings(): returns the data to send in the GET request


#====== SETTINGS AREA ======
def request():
    url = "https://httpbin.org/anything"
    return url

def settings():
    data = {'example':'example'}
    return (data)

#===========================================================
```

main.py

```py
import importlib

import multio
import qdarkstyle
import trio
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from asks import Session


module = importlib.import_module("get_module")


class TaskWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    totalChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    validChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    invalidChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TaskWorker, self).__init__(parent)
        self._total = 0
        self._valid = 0
        self._invalid = 0

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=totalChanged)
    def total(self):
        return self._total

    @total.setter
    def total(self, value):
        if self._total == value:
            return
        self._total = value
        self.totalChanged.emit(self._total)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=validChanged)
    def valid(self):
        return self._valid

    @valid.setter
    def valid(self, value):
        if self._valid == value:
            return
        self._valid = value
        self.validChanged.emit(self._valid)

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, notify=invalidChanged)
    def invalid(self):
        return self._invalid

    @invalid.setter
    def invalid(self, value):
        if self._invalid == value:
            return
        self._invalid = value
        self.invalidChanged.emit(self._invalid)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def check(self):
        async def worker1(s):
            if module.method.lower() == "get":
                r = await s.get(module.request(), params=module.settings())
            elif module.method.lower() == "post":
                r = await s.post(module.request(), data=module.settings())
            # if any(x in r.status_code for x in module.error):
            if str(r.status_code) in module.error:
                print("BAD -- " + module.request())
                self.total += 1
                self.invalid += 1
            else:
                print("GOOD -- " + module.request())
                self.total += 1
                self.valid += 1
                print(r.text)

        async def worker2(s):
            if module.method.lower() == "get":
                r = await s.get(module.request(), params=module.settings())
            elif module.method.lower() == "post":
                r = await s.post(module.request(), data=module.settings())
            # if any(x in r.status_code for x in module.error):
            if str(r.status_code) in module.error:
                print("BAD -- " + module.request())
                self.total += 1
                self.invalid += 1
            else:
                print("GOOD -- " + module.request())
                self.total += 1
                self.valid += 1
                print(r.text)

        async def example():
            s = Session(connections=module.connections)
            for i in range(40):
                async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
                    nursery.start_soon(worker1, s)
                    nursery.start_soon(worker2, s)

        multio.init("trio")
        trio.run(example)


class Menu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Status Codes")
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        self.resize(500, 350)
        self.ok = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            "200: <font color='green'>0</font>",
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter,
        )
        self.bad = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            "400: <font color='yellow'>0</font>",
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter,
        )
        self.total = QtWidgets.QLabel(
            "Total: <font color='#00FF00'>0</font>",
            alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter,
        )
        lay.addWidget(self.ok)
        lay.addWidget(self.bad)
        lay.addWidget(self.total)

        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()

        self.worker = TaskWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.worker.totalChanged.connect(self.updateTotal)
        self.worker.validChanged.connect(self.updateValid)
        self.worker.invalidChanged.connect(self.updateInvalid)
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.worker.check)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def updateTotal(self, total):
        self.total.setText("Total: <font color='#F40D30'>%s</font>" % (total))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def updateValid(self, valid):
        self.ok.setText("200: <font color='green'>%s</font>" % (valid))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def updateInvalid(self, invalid):
        self.bad.setText("400: <font color='#00FF00'>%s</font>" % (invalid))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())
    ex = Menu()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! 
I've tried your code with my original one, and while now the GUI actually shows up and doesn't freeze while the requests are sent, the QLabels still don't change dynamically, it still only updates them once all the requests are sent.

Comment: @Liam You could share the module "get_module" to be able to test.

Comment: Yes! Thank you a lot for your help! I have however simplified my code to keep some things private so I've also simplified the module as well! While rewriting the module so that it coincides with the simplified code I gave and you corrected, I've changed a few things to make it work, and the same issue happens again Here's the module code and the modified main code (I tried seperating the both with filename) https://ghostbin.com/paste/7dhh3